# Private variable has different value in async method

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a two private variable which are populated when the form loads.

```
private int _days = 0;
private int _calc = 0;

public override void OnLoad(obejct sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    _days = 2;
    _calc = 500;
    ...
}
```

These private variables are then used with an `async` method of the form. This method is an overridden method of this form's base class method.

```
public override async void Populate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    int b = _days; // _days = 0 here, but should be 2
    int x = _calc; // _calc is 500
    ...
}
```

When debugging and looking at the private variable `_days`. It is set to `0` here, but looking at the other variable `_calc` is the desired `500`.

Why is that?

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] it would allow others to repeat your problem, and will give a better chance of you being given a solution.

Comment: Could you add `MessageBox.Show("OnLoad --- _days = " + _days + "_calc = " + _calc);` after you assign those two variables in `OnLoad` and same message but with `Populate in first part` inside `Populate` function before you use them?